# UIImagePickerController Function Not Working Correctly for Camera, Works for Photo Album

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm writing a function to add an image to a UIImageView with UIImagePickerController. Once the image is added, a Share button is then enabled - both the camera and the photo-album let me pick an image and add it to the UIImageView, but the share button is only enabled when I pick an image from the Photo Album. When I pick an image from the Camera, the button doesn't work. Any idea why? Here is the relevant code:

```
//Pick Image from Album
@IBAction func pickAnImageFromAlbum(_ sender: Any) {
    let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    pickerController.allowsEditing = true
    present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
//Pick Image from Camera
@IBAction func pickAnImageFromCamera(_ sender: Any) {
    let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.sourceType = .camera
    pickerController.allowsEditing = true
    present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
//Send image to UIImageViewer, enable Share Button
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        shareButton.isEnabled = true
        imageViewer.image = image
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Do you get the image in the imageview when you pick from the camera? I mean does the `imageViewer.image = image` line gets called when you pick the image from camera?

Comment: you should get originalImage infoKey when using the camera

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com, Thanks - I do get the image, which is what is really confusing me.

Comment: @LeoDabus - Thanks for the idea, I just tried that as well and still no luck. Really not sure why the image appears but not the share button

Comment: FWIW: If I set shareButton.isEnabled = true in ViewWillAppear(), the shareButton is enabled after I pick an image with the Camera (it's set to false normally to prevent sharing before an image is chosen).

Comment: Interesting. What happens if you cache the UIImage in your VC? If it's there, you can always leave the shareButton enabled and pop up an alert if there's no image. (I do that in my single screen apps because I think it's more... user friendly that disabled buttons. It also is a way to do some simple onboarding for new users.))

Comment: A popup alert instead of disabling the button is a great idea -  I'm new to swift so I'm not sure how to do that but I'll do some research and give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: I just couldn't get the share button to enable but the UIAlertController pop up works great - thanks for the suggestion